# How to load helper into another helper in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I want to use the `distance_of_time_in_words` function from `DateHelper` into another Helper.

How to use symfony `DateHelper` into my custom Helper?

Any hint is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

Added following line before calling distance_of_time_in_words() function in my helper.

```
sfProjectConfiguration::getActive()->loadHelpers(array('Date'));
```

That is what I needed, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way, is to define your helper globally, in your `apps/frontend/config/settings.yml`:

```
all:
  .settings:
    standard_helpers:  [Partial, Cache, I18N, Date]
```

This way, all the helpers from `standard_helpers` will always be loaded and available in your view.

Ps: be careful to not override your own `standard_helpers` but just add `Date` to the end.

Comment: Thanks for reply @j0k now I am getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function distance_of_time_in_words().